# Rally Test Set and Test Cases results update in karate scenarios run

Tags: karate, rally

I'm trying to figure out how I can automatically update test case results for Test Set -> Test cases in Rally through karate automation scripts. I want to be able to run my test scripts, which will then update the test case results in Rally automatically to Pass or Fail.

Is there any way to do that with karate? I'm using karate along with JUnit.

We tried with Jenkins TRAUS service but it updates the Rally test case with a feature results not individual scenario wise.

Is there a tag like @Rally in karate scenario so that individual test cases in Rally can be updated

Comment: all available options are in linked answer, if you need more, do consider contributing code